# BST preorder non recursive - what is on the stack?

Tags: binary-search-tree

I am learning BST and I am trying to understand that is the stack content running a preorder non-recursive algorithm on this tree? I've created it myself and I want to understand how do I put the data on stack here, so if I would like to determine what is the stack content after the 3rd node or any n-th node? I know that in pre order I visit the root first, but I am having difficulties with understanding what goes on the stack? I am not familiar with Java and the explanations I've found online are not helping me much, and I would be very grateful for some pointers here on how to get better with this?

[my tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgkfM.png)